# A bound for a product in BMO

Tags: real-analysis, harmonic-analysis

**The question:** Let's consider $f\in L^\infty(\mathbb{T})$ and $g\in BMO(\mathbb{T})$. I'm trying to figure out if the following inequality is true
$$
\|fg\|_{BMO}\leq C\|f\|_{L^\infty}\|g\|_{BMO}.
$$

**My approach:** I tried using the duality with $H^1$. I get
$$
\|fg\|_{BMO}\leq \sup_{\|h\|_{H^1}\leq 1} 2\|f\|_{L^\infty}\|g\|_{BMO}\||h|\|_{H^1}.
$$
So, if in the periodic case we have $h\in H^1\rightarrow |h|\in H^1$, I'm done.

In the real line, in order $H h\in L^1$ (H is the Hilbert transform) one needs $h$ with zero mean (this implies that $h\in H^1\rightarrow |h|\in H^1$ isn't true). However, this restriction seems like it might be bypassed in the periodic setting. For instance let's take $h(x)=c$ with $c$ a constant. Then $h\in H^1$ and $|h|\in H^1$.

I'm not very familiar with harmonic analysis, so, this question could be quite trivial for an expert.

Comment: I gave an answer at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/611201/a-bound-for-the-product-of-two-functions-in-bmo

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, your answer only says that my approach is wrong. It doesn't say anything on the bound, right?

Comment: That example shows that a product of a BMO function and a bounded function need not have BMO, so the desired inequality is false.